# How to use post method in mvc pattern in Android?

Tags: android, json, spring-mvc

I'm new to implementing MVC pattern with JSON post method in Android. I want to post below data using JSON to this URL (http://xx.xxx.xx/xx/xxx/register). How to use MVC patern in Android.Can someone help me how to use MVC in Android.

```
METHOD
POST

HEADER
“Content-Type:application/json”

{
   "email":"rupa@nisostech.com",
   "password":"tushar",
   "password2":"tushar",
   "name":"tushar",
   "username":"Abhi",
   "roleId":4  
}
```

Comment: Web Methods <--------------------------------------> MVC

Comment: Mou : What is this ?

Comment: Web Methods used and MVC are independent

Answer (score 0):

Anju patal,

if you want to post a request you can use a http (post) method by using httpclient. but MVC is a pattern/design. for more about MVC -http://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/